# Explicit custom ordering/sorting of WPF CollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting

I'm trying to add some SortDescriptions to a CollectionView, but can't quite figure out how to get the behavior I'm after.

Essentially I'd like to sort first by a datetime, and then sort by a 2nd property (string) but in a specific order. On the pure c#/linq side of things I've done this in the past in an ugly way such as:

```
List<string> regionOrder = new List<string> { "AS", "CE", "KC", "NA", "LAM" };
results = results.OrderBy(x => x.Day).ThenBy(x => regionOrder.IndexOf(x.Region)).ToList();

return new DataCollectionResult<DailyBuildPlan> {Results = results, Error = error};
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve this using a CollectionView's sort descriptions? I assume it's fine to add multiple sort descriptions, but I'm not sure how to get the custom ordering I require on the 2nd property

e.g.

```
MyCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Day", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
MyCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Region", ListSortDirection.MyCustomOrder));
```